# Run cronjob error Undefined index: REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, apache-2.4, command-line-interface

I have problems with cronjob & php cli blesta billing, I confused the issue in php/server or there is an error database. I see php **cli** already installed.

**Cron Command**

> */5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/domains/member.domain.com/public_html/index.php cron

**Error:** Undefined index: REQUEST_URI

> ```
> Unable to deliver 1 invoice to client #31661 via Email due to error: Undefined index: REQUEST_URI
> Unable to deliver 1 invoice to client #31331 via Email due to error: Undefined index: REQUEST_URI
> Unable to deliver 1 invoice to client #31158 via Email due to error: Undefined index: REQUEST_URI
> Unable to deliver 1 invoice to client #31155 via Email due to error: Undefined index: REQUEST_URI
> ```

```
The deliver invoices task has completed.
Attempting to run all tasks for Wpfastest.
Attempting to apply credits to open invoices.
There are no invoices to which credits may be applied.
The apply credits task has completed.
Attempting to provision paid pending services.
The paid pending services task has completed.
Attempting to unsuspend paid suspended services.
The unsuspend services task has completed.
Attempting to process service changes.
The process service changes task has completed.
Attempting to process renewing services.
The process renewing services task has completed.
```

---

**Server Spec:**

Php 5.6, 
Apache 2.4, 
Mariadb5.5.

---

> [root@s3eagle ~]# php /home/mydomain/test-cli.php
>
> Running from CLI[root@superspeed ~]#

**text-cli.php**

```
<?php 
if(php_sapi_name()==="cli")
  echo("Running from CLI"); 
else
  echo("Not Running from CLI");
```

---

**php -v**

> [root@s3eagle ~]# php -v
>
> PHP 5.6.30 ***(cli)*** (built: Jan 20 2017
>
> 07:54:54) Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.6.0,
>   Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

---

**php -m**

```
    [root@s3eagle ~]# php -m
    [PHP Modules]
ares
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
gnupg
hash
iconv
igbinary
imagick
imap
intl
ionCube Loader
json
ldap
libxml
lzf
mailparse
mbstring
mcrypt
memcache
memcached
mhash
msgpack
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
OAuth
odbc
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
pspell
rar
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
snmp
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tcpwrap
tokenizer
uploadprogress
uri_template
uuid
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
yaml
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured)
```

Maybe somebody got the idea for this. Sorry if untidy.....

Comment: I think this is a useful question.  Running a web script from cron is a pretty common mistake.  The title of the question will make it easy to find.

Answer (score 3):

You're running a php script from a cron job.

The php script appears to expect to be run from a web browser, hence REQUEST_URI.  It also might be a script run by the script, so you might have to dig.

Comment: This just happened to me, other blesta users may not experience this.

Maybe you have an idea php extension that needs to be installed again?

Comment: You need to run the script from the web server, for example by using wget in your from job